# GCC/C++ Compiler warning for a line with missing assignment?

Tags: c++, gcc

My knowledge of C and compilers is pretty outdated at this point and I came across code like this a couple days ago:

```
foo + bar + quz;
```

The line should read:

```
foo += bar + quz;
```

We're compiling with `-Wall` and I expected the compiler to at least throw a warning.

Am I missing something or is the first example a perfectly reasonable and often-seen line in C/C++?

Here is the info from `gcc -v`:

```
# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 6.3.0-18' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
```

**Edit**

I created a short example to show my issue: https://godbolt.org/g/WWKNCv

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static const char FOO[] = "hello";

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    std::string a = FOO;
    std::string c = "world";
    a + ", " + c;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

I can compile this successfully with `g++ -Wall test.cpp` and there is no compiler warning for the line `a + ", " + c`. Can someone explain why?

I do know that `string` has an *operator+* (after reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+/). Is this an example where the compiler can not know that the line is useless?

Comment: When I use `-Wall` I get a warning "statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, *for builtin types* gcc will emit a "statement has no effect" warning, at least at some warning level - try with `-Wextra`. However if any of the operands is of class type with an overloaded operator (possibly not completely trivial or, if trivial, whose definition is not inline) the compiler has no reason to suspect that the statement is useless - nobody said that overloaded operators have the same semantics of builtin ones.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/g/SDb3eK)

Comment: Please provide the exact command you use for compiling. I suspect you have some other flag, like `-Wno-unused` enabled that suppresses those warnings for you.

Comment: @K.Kirsz I added a short example.

Comment: Well in that case i think the explaination lies in the answer by @MatteoItalia - it works for builtin types - std::string isn't one.

Comment: @K.Kirsz  right, I'll accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(moving from a comment)

I'm pretty sure that, *for builtin types*, gcc will emit a "statement has no effect" warning, at least at some warning level - try with `-Wextra` - *edit* actually, I see now that it should be included even at `-Wall`.

However if any of the operands is of class type with an overloaded `operator+` (possibly not completely trivial or, if trivial, whose definition is not inline) the compiler has no reason to suspect that the statement is useless - nobody said that overloaded operators have the same semantics of builtin ones. Think about all those `cout<<"hello world!";`, if the compiler assumed the same semantics as for builtin types they would all generate "statement has no effect" warnings.